# Tomcat Context URL

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat7

My Application is "MyApp" that runs on tomcat 7 and use spring framework,

I have the following access URLs:

```
1 - https://myserver:8443/MyApp/      for the Application Web
2 - https://myserver:8443/MyApp/Rest  for the Application Web Services
```

And my application is sets on the path:

```
...\tomcat\webapps\MyApp\
```

I need to change the URLs to be without changing the application folder:

```
1 - https://myserver:8443/MyApp/Admin   for the Application Web(need to change MyApp to be Admin)
2 - https://myserver:8443/MyApp/Rest    for the Application web services
```

Any Idea?

Comment: You need to assign it in spring security and Just change in request mapping.

Comment: How can i change the request mapping?

Comment: Using spring security configuration